# How do I clear existing data from a cell if it doesn't follow data validation rule

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a column "C" with data validation rules that change based on the content in column "A".  Column C will reject invalid entries, but will leave an invalid entry if the value was there before column A was changed.  I want to clear the cell in column C if it contains invalid data, but leave it if the existing value is valid within the new validation rules.

I've read that there is no command to determine if the data in a cell is invalid, but you can reverse engineer a check by comparing the Data Validation range to the value. I've tried different ways to compare my value to my validation range, but have failed.

```
     function onEdit(){

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AllStaff"); 
   var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
   var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CategoryValidation");

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 19 &&  activeCell.getRow() > 3){

    activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearDataValidations();  

    var category = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();


    var categoryIndex = category[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;


        var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, categoryIndex, datass.getLastRow()) 
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).setAllowInvalid(false).setHelpText("Please choose from list").build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(validationRule);

    var checkValidation = activeCell.offset(0,2).getValue();

I have tried things like:

    var validationIndex = validationRange.indexOf(checkValidation);
    var validationIndex = validationRange[0].indexOf(checkValidation);
    var validationIndex = validationRange[0].getRowIndex(checkValidation);
```

I expected to receive an index number of 0 or greater if the value of checkValidation is in my validationRange and -1 if it is not (so I can apply an If statement to clear data if index ===-1).  Instead, I receive errors like:
TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of undefined. (line 25, file "Code")
TypeError: Cannot call method "getRowIndex" of undefined. (line 25, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: would it be possible for you to share the entire code? A whole bunch of things seem to come up as **undefined**. Starting from `datass`, `categoryIndex`, `activeCell` & so on.

Comment: I've added the additional code.  I guess I was trying too hard to keep my post short.

Comment: Could you share a sanitized version of your Sheet? Right now is not easy to visualize what you mean.